# Chrome: window.opener.myFunction() works with Developer tools open, but does not work when Developer tools is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Upon "submit" from child window, I want to call a function (myFunction()) in the parent window.  All three forms of my code in Child window work perfectly when "Developer tools" is open, but none of the three work when "Developer tools" is closed.

Parent window code: (This code is in an iframe id="MainWindow")

```js
if (Event.target == document.getElementById("AddUser")) {
  var Win = window.open("/HitsAdministrator/UserManagement.php?Mode=AddUserForm", "", "width=600,height=350,top=150,left=200");
  .
  .
  .
}

function MyTest() {
    alert("It worked!");
}
```

Child window code:  (This code is in a popup window.)

```js
//window.parent.opener.MyTest();
//self.opener.MyTest();
self.opener.top.document.getElementById("MainWindow").contentWindow.MyTest();
```

I have tried this on several browser combinations as follows:

Chrome Windows: Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Works with Developer tools open.  Does not work with Developer tools closed.

Chrome Linux: Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Works with Developer tools open.  Does not work with Developer tools closed.

Edge Windows: Version 44.17763.831.0 / 18.17763
Works fine.

Firefox Linux: Version 71.0 (64-bit)
Works fine.

My user community is about 80% Chrome, so this needs to work in Chrome.  Is this a Chrome bug or am I doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: try `window.parent.MyTest()` rather then `window.parent.opener.MyTest()`

Comment: This generated error:  Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.MyTest is not a function.  Thanks for the suggestion.